# How can I have a separate setup process and home page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am currently building an app that has a first page with two buttons: 'New users -->" and "Existing users -->". The goal is for new users to click their button and go through a setup process that ends with their home page that is saved when the app is closed. The next time a user opens the app, once they click their existing users button, I want the app to open to the home page the setup process ends at. How do I achieving this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoRouter (from flutter team) plugin for handling this scenario and navigation.

https://pub.dev/packages/go_router

While initialising the router, you can provide `redirect` where you can handle if user should be navigated to the setup screen or home screen.

Comment: I just implemented GoRouter, but how do I also use shared_preferences or something for the device to remember contents of home page when it directs users to it (even after device is closed).

Answer (score 0):

Use database / shared preference / secure storage to store whether the setup process was completed and what data was saved.

Now if you are using any framework like `GetX` or something you can easily navigate to the desired pages or you can use `Navigator.to`.... if not using a framework.

you can use something like

```
bool isSetupDone = // get from storage
```

the use this Boolean value to either alert, show/hide button/ popup message accordingly as per your usecase.

Comment: Can you give me an example of specific code w/ shared preferences?